# Getting Neo4j node and relationship data without duplicates

Tags: neo4j

I have the graph below and I would like to get the 2 Task nodes (i.e. the two nodes that are displayed with dates). Then I would like to get the WAS_BOUGHT relationships and then the MAKING_USE_OF relationships. Obviously I would like this data to correlate to the given tasks being matched. I then take that data and create a Task object in my application and store a List of the WAS_BOUGHT relationships and a List of the MAKING_USE_OF relationships as properties of the object.

[image: groceries graph example]

I tried to run the query below but I get a lot of duplicates. Every time the relationship data arrives I get the Task data again, duplicated. I would prefer to condition the data already in neo4j before parsing it through to my application. I just feel like it will be a lot more efficient that way.

```
MATCH (t:Task)-[r1:WAS_BOUGHT]->()
MATCH (t:Task)-[r2:MAKING_USE_OF]->()
WHERE ID(t) IN [40,60]
RETURN t, r1, r2
```

I can split this up into 3 queries to avoid duplicates but it then will require a connection to the database 3 times which seems really inefficient.

```
MATCH (t:Task)-[]->()
WHERE ID(t) IN [40,60]
RETURN t

MATCH (t:Task)-[r1:WAS_BOUGHT]->()
WHERE ID(t) IN [40,60]
RETURN r1

MATCH (t:Task)-[r2:MAKING_USE_OF]->()
WHERE ID(t) IN [40,60]
RETURN r2
```

Any idea how I can write a query to get the data in the format below without duplicates?

Task node, WAS_BOUGHT relationships, MAKING_USE_OF relationships for ID=40

Task node, WAS_BOUGHT relationships, MAKING_USE_OF relationships for ID=60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a single row for each `Task` node

```
// find the specific task nodes and WAS_BOUGHT relatioships 
MATCH (t:Task)-[r1:WAS_BOUGHT]->()
WHERE ID(t) IN [40,60]

// aggregate the WAS_BOUGHT relationships per task
WITH t, collect(r1) AS bought

// with each task find what was used to shop
MATCH (t)-[r2:MAKING_USE_OF]->()

// return the task with the aggregate WAS_BOUGHT and MAKING_USE relationships
RETURN t, bought, collect(r2) AS making_use
```